# Smartphone fingerprint plus iris scanning for login

Tags: authentication, account-security, authorization, spoofing, smartphone

I have often thought about the fact that when intimate relationship partners live together they eventually tend to sneak over your shoulder and gain access to your password on either your mobile phone or your pc.

Furthermore, swipable screen locks have been invented on smartphones because people get fed up typing the password each time, but these are easier to observe and break.

So, with fingerprints this problem is partially taken care of, but what if, while you are asleep, your partner grabs your phone and finger and uses it to unlock your phone, and then read, or even modify, or even delete your data?

For this reason, I was thinking a solution would be a simultaneous fingerprint reader and iris scanner to make sure you are actually awake while unlocking and using your phone.

Has this been implemented anywhere?

What other solutions to this problem might be available?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is basically whether any phone support requiring multiple methods of identification in order to unlock the device.  Correct?

Comment: No, I'm just wondering if it is possible to add an iris scan to the fingerprint authentication to ensure someone doesn't log you in while asleep with your eyes closed. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this belong here. It is a trust issue to me, not a security issue. If your are facing an enemy who can sneak into your room, and use your fingerprints, you have a bigger problem. You asked in the comment if face recognition work if you are asleep... I think you should talk to your wife/husband.

Comment: Some phone companies could be developing this feature, but none would reveal it until the release date. But there is no shortcut to security; I'd say one needs to be ready to punch in hard to remember passwords and also be ready to refresh them periodically to get some serious protection.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson "to ensure someone doesn't log you in while asleep with your eyes closed" - On an iPhone using Face ID you can enable the option to check during unlocking if you are looking at the screen. So it does not work with your eyes closed. Possibly other phones have a similar feature.

Comment: "_What other solutions to this problem might be available?_" How about wearing [lockable gloves](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=lockable+gloves) at night?

Comment: If you are worried about your partner deleting things of your phone while you sleep then I think you need a new partner

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phones doesn't use retina scanning.  The retina is the back of the eyeball (something only an optometrist would see if your eye was dilated), or you used a very specialized scanner.

Some new phones support iris recognition, which is the pattern of the surface of your eye made up on unique features such as blood vessels.  This would prevent the issue you're concerned about (access while not awake).

I'm not aware of any phones that support requiring multiple methods of authentication to unlock the phone.  Many phones offer the ability to unlock the phone via a biometric feature (face, finger, etc.) in addition to a PIN (in case the biometric fails).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder whether in addition to face and fingerprint unlock for logging in someone will implement iris+fingerprint in the near future.

Comment: Also, does face recognition work if you are asleep and someone scans your face with the eyes closed, or do the writes have to be open for face recognition login to work? Thanks.

Comment: Facial recognition will depend on the vendor who implemented the feature.  Apples actually looks at your face in 3D, and can work through glasses, other companies can't handle glasses/eyes closed and only use a 2D image.

Comment: Unfortunately, facial recognition from Apple is so bad that there are reports of people's _children_ being able to unlock their parents' phones simply by having a similar face.